# How to uninstall VMWare Workstation 14 on Windows 7 (X64)

Tags: windows, windows-installer, vmware-workstation, uninstallation, vmware-player

When I tried to manually uninstall VMWare Workstation 14... It gives me this error...[Windows installer Service Could Not Be Accessed ...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3SmuA.png). I'm using corporate machine, could this possibly mean I have to contact my sys admins and have them remove it? Has anyone had this problem before and solved it?

Comment: Regular users may be allowed to trigger install / uninstall of software on corporate machines, but in my real-world experience they are generally  not allowed to do so. Corporate machines are usually standardized, locked-down [SOEs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Operating_Environment).

Comment: Agree... we are allowed to install/uninstall software on corporate machine (but limited to corporate initially installed softwares). However, we actually download & /install Workstations ourselves(employee). But I don't nderstand why it would trigger the error while uninstalling it! @SteinÅsmul

Comment: OK, hold on - let me add the original answer I wrote for you before realizing you were in a controlled, corporate environment.

Comment: If you see the link I posted above... the error acutally says the "Machine might be running in a safe mode" and I was thinking maybe it's because of a corporate thing... I might be wrong though

Comment: FIXED: Turns out this was a corporate thing!!! I had my technician/admin uninstalled the program. 

Thanks for participating!!

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't going to post this - I think I misunderstood your scenario - but here goes, maybe see if some ideas pop up:

---

A few questions:

- Does this happen with other packages on the box as well?
- Do you see the same problem with the VMWare package on other boxes?
- Do co-workers - with similar login credentials and rights - see the same problem(s)?
- Did you ask you system administrator what policies apply for the install / repair of MSI packages? Maybe group policy blocks them? Is this a package you downloaded yourself, or is it "blessed" by a sys-admin?
- Do you know if this is a 32-bit or 64-bit package? Do you have a tool to open the MSI? If you got Orca - open the MSI and go to `View => Summary Information...` - what does the Platform field say?

---

When things like this happens, you should generally first hit the vendor site looking for `user forums`, `knowledge bases`, `support contact information` etc... Unless you have a service agreement, in which case you should obviously just call them and enjoy some nice waiting music.

A quick search:

- https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/2004136
- https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/1031032 (for installations inside virtuals)
- https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/1004802 (for installations inside virtuals)

Maybe try `msiexec /regserver` first - it seems to be the most harmless option. My guess is that this is a policy thing which locks the whole Windows Installer service from running. **What security software do you have installed on the box?**

Comment: 1. Does this happen with other packages on the box as well?
- This is the first time I had this problem... and I don't want to try uninstalling any other programs/packages to test it out.

Comment: Try to run another package in modify or repair mode? (not entirely without risk of reset user data). Make it a small package - Orca perhaps? Orca is quick to reinstall - do you have Visual Studio installed? Then you have the MSI to install Orca readily available in the SDK folders - search for `Orca-x86_en-us.msi`.

Comment: - This is the first time I had this problem... and I don't want to try uninstalling any other programs/packages to test it out.


- Like I said again, I don't want to remove/uninstall anything else to test this out


- I was the only one who had that nightmare to jump into Workstation Pro 14 version that recently came out. 


-I have not contacted my sys admins, that's why I'm asking if anyone had this problem before and had to contact admins 


- I do not and I don't remember, but I believe it was 64-bit package.

Comment: Turns out this was a corporate thing!!! I had my technician/admin uninstalled the program. 

Thanks for participating!!

Comment: Yes, pretty much as expected - a little unusual that you didn't get a clearer error message. You may be in a "hybrid" environment where users have "some rights", but not enough to do what they need all the time.

Comment: Why does "good luck with that" come to mind? :-). Sorry, no offence. Hope you get to do what you need to do. It is hard to be a developer / tester without admin rights. Pretty much impossible. But, onwards - set the controls for the heart of the sun! :-)